# How should drywall be prepared for bullnose corner bead?

Tags: drywall

I have a handyman doing work in my house. Part of the work is drywall with bullnose corners. How should the corners be prepped for installation of the bullnose?

The pictures below shows how it's currently done. Is this just ugly or is it problematic?

Some specific questions:

- Will the inconsistent cut depth of the bevel cause issues?
- Is the bevel cut ok, or do the two pieces of drywall need to be cut back, say, for expansion purposes?
- Does the corner overlap need to be cut back to not overlap?
- Are screws (or special screws) supposed to be used for attaching the bullnose?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Drywall installed with the intention of using bullnose corners should end at the framing line. In the case of existing drywall, cut it back to not overlap or shave the corner off. It's just a matter of gaining clearance, so there really are no rules. The drywall does not support the center of the bead, so it need not touch.

Most folks use drywall nails or narrow-crown staples for attaching bead of any type. Screws tend to either stay above flush or tug things around too much. Bead needs to be precisely positioned with respect to the wall plane to avoid ski jumps and humps. Lay a straightedge on the wall to check that. Ideally the finished bead surface will be slightly above each wall plane to allow for a tapered skim between.

Answer (score 1):

The edges of cornering panels should end short so that there is room for the nosing's turning radius. Where paneling protrudes, slice it off with a utility knife.

Check that it is plumb (by level) and straight (by eye). Laser levels are helpful here.

If you can run your finishing trowel up and down the nosing, sliding on one end along the nose's edge and the other on the drywall panel, without hitting a screw, you are fine.

Nails require less head clearance.

Or use no fastener and paste it on with blobs of setting compound every foot or so. I find that sometimes fasteners cause corner beads to distort. Dry fit first. Then, with a 90min hardening time you still have at least 20 minutes to adjust.

Comment: Plumb isn't important with corner bead. It needs to be set to the wall faces.

Comment: @isherwood will align better with cabinetry/furniture and other nearby corners (e.g. protruding wall ends, windows/doors), and this is the last chance to adjust the panels. I always check, and I have caught my own and others' framing mistakes

Comment: Adjust panels? Now you're talking about drywall and framing. That's a whole different conversation. :)